# Correct route for a singular nested resource

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes, nested-resources

I have 2 resources, one being a nested resource of another:

`parent_resource` and `child_resource`.

This gives me the following routes:

```
somesite.com/parent_resources/14
somesite.com/parent_resources/14/child_resources/1
```

However there is only ever going to be a single `child_resource` for each `parent_resource`, so to someone using the site this is very confusing. I would like the child_resource paths to look like this:

```
somesite.com/parent_resource/14/child_resource
somesite.com/parent_resource/14/child_resource/edit
etc
```

What is the correct way to do this?

My routes.rb

```
resources :parent_resources do

   resource :child_resource do
   end

end
```

From the rails guide to routing:

```
A singular resourceful route generates these helpers:

new_geocoder_path returns /geocoder/new
edit_geocoder_path returns /geocoder/edit
geocoder_path returns /geocoder
```

But what about show?

My routes generated by rake routes:

```
parent_resource_child_resource      POST   /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resource(.:format)                 child_resources#create


new_parent_resource_child_resource  GET    /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resource/new(.:format)             child_resources#new

edit_parent_resource_child_resource GET    /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resource/edit(.:format)            child_resources#edit

                                    GET    /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resource(.:format)                 child_resources#show

                                    PUT    /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resource(.:format)                 child_resources#update

                                    DELETE /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resource(.:format)                 child_resources#destroy
```

Comment: You should pass a plural name to `resources` and a singular name to `resource`. You're passing singular to both.

Comment: Ah, I see you've corrected the names. And please verify that the named route doesn't work instead of relying solely on `rake routes` which may sometimes omit named routes that work. Because this scheme works fine for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your routes, define the child resource using the singular `resource` method:

```
resources :parent_resources do
  resource :child_resource
end
```

By convention, the controller for the child will still be ChildResourcesController, plural.

Rails has a pretty good guide to routing. See the section on [singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that this doesn't generate a named route for the child_resource#show. I only get a create, an edit and a new.

Comment: Yes you do. If your parent is "user" and your child is "profile", you should have `user_profile_path(@user)`

Comment: I only have the following paths shown using rake routes:parent_resource_child_resources POST   /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resources(.:format)                 child_resources#create
       new_parent_resource_child_resources GET    /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resources/new(.:format)             child_resources#new
      edit_parent_resource_child_resources GET    /parent_resources/:parent_resource_id/child_resources/edit(.:format)            child_resources#edit

Comment: Also, notice that the singular resource method should take a singular name. The plural "child_resources" in your output seems wrong.

Comment: Good spot. I had accidentally changed it to the plural. Unfortunately when I switch it back I am left with only the same three routes (just singular). parent_resource_child_resource(@parent_resource) yields an undefined method error from the page which contains it.

Comment: I've pasted my routes into the question.